How to configure login redirect uri in Blazor WASM?
When I clicked the login button in development environment, the browser always redirected to production URL (I wanted the development URL). I had two redirect URI in Azure AD. How to configure the redirect URL? I had checked the official documents offered by Microsoft, but I can't find the answer.
Redirect URI (I put them to Azure AD B2C):

https://localhost/authentication/login-callback (for development)
https://www.example.com/authentication/login-callback (for production)

I created blazor wasm project with auth function. I had the following config in appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://example.b2clogin.com/example.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_UserFlow1",
    "ClientId": "88888888-8888-8888-abdf-888888888",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
}

This is my .csproj file:
<!--   remove useless contents     -->
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.3"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.3" PrivateAssets="all"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="8.0.3"/>

When I clicked to login button, page navigated to "authentication/login". Here's the codes:
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <button @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

I want my project to redirect to right URL.

did you try: Log in  and with if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) you can set the MyDevelopmentOrProductionUrl
